# 'onEventDeleted' trigger when click on cancel button on the event editor

Tags: dhtmlx, dhtmlx-scheduler

Im using [DHTMLX scheduler](http://dhtmlx.com) and I'm trying to delete an event when click on the delete button in the popup event editor, below is my code reference.

```
scheduler.attachEvent("onEventDeleted", function(id,ev){
    $.ajax({
         url : "calendar.php",
         type: 'post',
         data: { event_id : id},
         success: function(e){
             if($.trim(e) === "success"){
                 alert("Event was successfully deleted");
             }
         }
  });
});
```

the above code works (The event was deleted successfully) but the problem is, the 'onEventDeleted' did also trigger when i click the cancel button from the popup editor. Any ideas, help, suggestions, recommendations, help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens only if you press cancel while creating a new event. In this case triggering onEventDeleted is expected since it removes a newly created event from a calendar.
In order not to send that update to the backend you can use this method 
http://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/api__scheduler_getstate.html

So if you update code like following everything should be good:

```
scheduler.attachEvent("onEventDeleted", function(id,ev){
    if(scheduler.getState().new_event)
      return;

    $.ajax({
         url : "calendar.php",
         type: 'post',
         data: { event_id : id},
         success: function(e){
             if($.trim(e) === "success"){
                 alert("Event was successfully deleted");
             }
         }
  });
});
```